# Large numbers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bigint

I have a Bigint column in my Table in SQL server as a Primary Key and when I request from a client with `axios` or `fetch` in React, it has a problem with ids like `9223372036854775800` and converts all of them to `9223372036854776000` !!!,

How can I fix that?

Comment: you should not use it as number, use string. and it's not related to reactjs. it's javascript issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: Send a string from the server and use [**`BigInt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: @adiga how can I use BigInt in react?

Comment: Click the link the in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolve this problem you can send on the front-end string instead of number. Native js not support big number. If you want work on front-end with big number, you can use bignumber js library: https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

In your case: 
 1. send string on front-end. 
 2. get number as string and create `BigNumber('9223372036854775800')`

Comment: Thank you, but this package in React makes an array of digits of number and not return number, but with https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer it is ok.

Answer (score 5):

To enable the BigInt in React as of now you have to add this comment to your code:

```
/* global BigInt */
```

Please, refer to [this](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11524#issuecomment-473790677).

Comment: this is an insane mine field. Thanks, fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your MySQL connection config, give a property

```
supportBigNumbers: true,
```